# Limited amount of radio in

Tags: php

To display a string from the database In the output the string is shown halfway
Like the following Sample in database

> PHP is a server scripting language

The output is as follows

> php

.

> Code to display

```
<input type="radio" name=<?php echo 'answare'.$r['id_q'];?> 
value=<?php echo $r['answare'];?> >
```

Comment: is this the exact output? I mean, is it also lowercase?
Can you try to write 'var_dump($r);' and share the output with us?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment

Answer (score 0):

You should always put quotes around attributes. Otherwise, a space in the attribute will end it.

```
<input type="radio" name="<?php echo 'answare'.$r['id_q'];?>"
    value="<?php echo htmlentities($r['answare']);?>" >
```

Using `htmlentities()` protects in case `$r['answare']` contains quotes or other special characters.

Comment: Should also make sure `$r['answare'];` doesn't contain any quotes.

Comment: @sajjadkazemi10 mark this answer as correct if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Its messy,

Please separate the 2, your view & your controller should not be mixing.

```
$radio = sprintf('<input type="radio" name="answare%s" value="%s" >', $r['id_q'], $r['answare'] );
```

Please look into template & mvcs.
Try Laravel, its an easy thing to pick up.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment

Comment: Its cool, I think if you have templates, your code would be easier to understand & maintain. You're doing well though. Happy coding

Comment: Thank you, engineer